# How to find the max value of a set of randomly generated numbers that is divisible by 7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, max

I know this might be a very easy question but I can't get my head around it. The question asks to generate 357 random numbers between 8 and 254 (inclusive) and print out the largest generated number that is exactly divisible by 7.

I wrote this program:

```
import random

def main():
    for x in range(357):
      print (random.randint(8,254)*7),

print

main()
```

which generates the numbers but I don't know how to get the max number out of it. I would really appreciate any help

Comment: You need to do some research on python to find out about collections.

Comment: Are the original numbers [8,...,254] supposed to be uniformly distributed?  What if none of the sample is divisible by 7?  Admittedly that's a very low probability, but how do you want to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension to generate the random numbers and then apply a filter to only keep those that are divisible by 7:

```py
import random

number = max(filter(lambda n: n % 7 == 0, [random.randint(8,254) for _ in range(357)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Concise one-liners are great, but here is an alternative approach that somewhat prioritizes readability for OP's reference. Namely, we save the randomly generated numbers in a list and perform sorting:

```
import random

def seven_max():
    nums = [random.randint(8,254) for _ in range(357)]
    nums.sort(reverse=True)
    for num in nums:
        if num % 7 == 0:
            return num
    return False # No such number
```

We first create a list of random numbers, defined as `nums`. Then, we sort the list in reverse order so that larger elements would come first. As we loop through this sorted array, we check if a number is divisible by 7. If it is, we return that number; if no number satisfies this condition, we return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with parameter `key`.

```
max((random.randint(8,254) for _ in range(357)),key =lambda x: x if x%7==0 else -1)
```

- `(random.randint(8,254) for _ in range(357))` is generator for producing 357 random values between 8 to 254.
- `key =lambda x: x if x%7==0 else -1` if number is divisible return it else -1. So, you get highest value that is divisible by 7.